# How to remove sensitive info from the default C# HttpClient logging

Tags: .net, logging, overriding, httpclient, hide

## Scenario

I call an external service using an access token, which needs to be provided as an query parameter called `token`.

### Logging output

When doing a GET request from C#, I see this logging (the real token is replaced by `eyJ0...` in this example):

```
[17:53:07 INF] Start processing HTTP request GET https://example.com/auth?token=eyJ0...

[17:53:07 INF] Sending HTTP request GET https://example.com/auth?token=eyJ0...

[17:53:07 INF] Received HTTP response headers after 140.3618ms - 200

[17:53:07 INF] End processing HTTP request after 142.3193ms - 200
```

### Change logging ?

Is there a a easy way using a mandatory custom Logging handler for the HttpClient/HttpClientfactory in such a way that the `token` query parameter is replaced by `***`?

Like:

```
[17:53:07 INF] Start processing HTTP request GET https://example.com/auth?token=***
```

#### Note 1:

This code is inside a library, so changing the log-level for the HttpClient/HttpClientfactory in the appsettings.json is not an option. It needs to be secure.

#### Note 2:

I register the HttpClient / RestEase as follows:

```cs
services
    .AddTransient<IMyClient, MyClient>()
    .AddHttpClient(options.HttpClientName, c => c.BaseAddress = options.ConnectUrl)
    .AddPolicyHandler((serviceProvider, request) => HttpClientRetryPolicies.GetPolicy(serviceProvider))
    .UseWithRestEaseClient<IMyApi>()
    ;
```